# How to add multiple CC addresses in VB script send mail

Tags: vbscript, lotus-notes, sendmail, lotusscript

How to add multiple email addresses in CC list for VB Script send mail.

```
option explicit 

' -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
' -- Create Lotus Notes email (and add attachment) using VB Script 
' --  
' -- Version 1.01 
' -- 
' -- Created by : Michael Green 
' --              migreen@westpac.com.au 
' --  
' -- Based on in-complete/partially working script from : 
' -- http://en.allexperts.com/q/Using-Lotus-Notes-1427/Creating-LotusNotes-email-using-1.htm 
' -- 
' -- Created     : 06/10/2009 
' -- Last Updated: 07/10/2009 
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Dim oSession        ' AS NotesSession 
Dim strServer 
Dim strUserName 
Dim strMailDbName 
Dim oCurrentMailDb  ' as NOTESDATABASE 
Dim oMailDoc        ' as NOTESDOCUMENT 
Dim ortItem         ' as NOTESRICHTEXTITEM 
Dim ortAttacment    ' as NOTESRICHTEXTITEM 
Dim oEmbedObject    ' as ???? 
dim cstrAttachment 
Dim blAttachment 

cstrAttachment = "c:\Temp\Telstra.xls" 

blAttachment = True 

' Start a session to notes 
wscript.echo "## Connecting to Lotus Notes session..." 
Set oSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession") 

wscript.echo("NotesVersion     : " & oSession.NotesVersion) 
wscript.echo("NotesBuildVersion: " & oSession.NotesBuildVersion) 
wscript.echo("UserName         : " & oSession.UserName) 
wscript.echo("EffectiveUserName: " & oSession.EffectiveUserName) 

wscript.echo "## GetEnvironmentString..." 
strServer = oSession.GetEnvironmentString("MailServer",True) 
wscript.echo("Server           :" & strServer) 

' eg. CN=Michael V Green/OU=CORPAU/OU=WBCAU/O=WBG 
strUserName = oSession.UserName 

strMailDbName = Left(strUserName, 1) & Right(strUserName, (Len(strUserName) - InStr(1, strUserName, "")))&".nsf" 
wscript.echo("MailDbName        :" & strMailDbName) 

wscript.echo "## Getting current Notes database..." 
' open the mail database in Notes 

set oCurrentMailDb = oSession.CurrentDatabase 

wscript.echo("fileName:" & oCurrentMailDb.fileName) 
wscript.echo("filePath:" & oCurrentMailDb.filePath) 
wscript.echo("server:" & oCurrentMailDb.server) 
wscript.echo("Title:" & oCurrentMailDb.Title) 

If oCurrentMailDb.IsOpen = True Then 
    ' Already open for mail 
    wscript.echo "## Lotus Notes mail database is already open !" 
Else 
    wscript.echo "## Opening Lotus Notes mail database..." 
    oCurrentMailDb.OPENMAIL 
End If 

' Create a document in the back end 
Set oMailDoc = oCurrentMailDb.CREATEDOCUMENT 

' Set the form name to memo 
OMailDoc.form = "Memo"  

with oMailDoc 
    .SendTo = "migreen@westpac.com.au" 
    .BlindCopyTo = "mgreen@ozemail.com.au"  
    .CopyTo = "migreen@westpac.com.au" 
    .Subject = "This is a test of VB scripting driving Lotus Notes 7 "  
end with 

set ortItem = oMaildoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body") 
with ortItem 
    .AppendText("Test of RTF Item append") 
    .AddNewLine(2) 
    .AppendText("Signature") 
End With 

' Create additional Rich Text item and attach it 
If blAttachment Then 
    Set ortAttacment = oMailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Attachment") 

    ' Function EMBEDOBJECT(ByVal TYPE As Short, ByVal CLASS As String, ByVal SOURCE As String, Optional ByVal OBJECTNAME As Object = Nothing) As Object 
    ' Member of lotus.NOTESRICHTEXTITEM 
    Set oEmbedObject = ortAttacment.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", cstrAttachment, "Attachment") 

End If 


wscript.echo "## Sending email..." 
with oMailDoc 
    .PostedDate = Now() 
    .SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = "True" 

    .send(false) 
end with 
wscript.echo "## Sent !" 


' close objects 
set oMailDoc       = nothing 
set oCurrentMailDb = nothing 
set oSession       = nothing
```

Comment: Try passing an array or a comma-separated string.

Comment: no if I pass that only first recipient in the list is receiving mails

Comment: You seem to be mixing [tag:lotusscript] and [tag:vbscript]. According to the documentation [`.OPENMAIL` method should only be used by LotusScript](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html) and COM should use `.OpenMailDatabase` which makes me think this script is a weird mix. Both are BASIC languages so there are going to be similarities.

Comment: Can you show some of your output in the question? Noticed there are lots of `WScript.Echo` statements in there that should output, would be nice to see where it falls over.

Comment: According to the documentation you should be using [`.OpenMailDatabase()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENMAILDATABASE_METHOD_DBDIRECTORY_COM.html) method as you are trying to do this in VBScript using COM components.

Comment: @Lankymart: nice to see your comments all over this thread. But you DO realize, that this code works, do you? The question is not "how do I debug this code and make it nicer", but to get multi values into the cc item...

Comment: @TorstenLink You know it works based off what? Personally I can't see how it works, seen as though the documentation suggests it shouldn't and the article the OP listed looks nothing like this code not to mention in the code comments it says *"Based on in-complete/partially working script"*.

Comment: @TorstenLink The OP may very well have asked how to add multiple email addresses to the cc, but they are only doing that because what they tried doesn't appear to work. That in itself suggest there is a fundamental issue with the code.

Comment: [This looks](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1692726) like your problem. Seems that multiple addresses isn't supported by `SendTo` some workarounds are suggested but probably not ideal. The article is referring to a VBA example but it's using COM and it's still BASIC so should apply.

Comment: Sorry, but your example proves the exact opposite of whatever you assume: if you read it to the end, there are lot of "it works" posts in that thread. I work with Lotus Notes since almost 20 years now. And you can believe me, that using an array for SendTo works, no matter what "seems" to be supported to you...

Comment: @TorstenLink Well I have none as this was a vbscript question and [you didn't seem to know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177469/how-to-add-multiple-cc-addresses-in-vb-script-send-mail#comment56107652_34179451) `As String` is not supported so all that experience counts for what exactly? I do have over 20 years experience with vbscript and classic asp if that counts.

Comment: OK, I'm out... Just one final sentence: SendTo, CopyTo and BlindCopyTo DO support multiple values, no matter what you read anywhere else.

Comment: @TorstenLink No need for that your amended answer makes it clearer and it appears as though my suggestion of `SendTo = Array("...", "...", "...")` works. The confusion for me came from lotusscript / vbscript and what the documentation stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an array to set the values

```vb
with oMailDoc 
    .SendTo = Array( "migreen@westpac.com.au", "mgreen@westpac.com.au", "green@westpac.com.au" )
    .BlindCopyTo = "mgreen@ozemail.com.au"  
    .CopyTo = "migreen@westpac.com.au" 
    .Subject = "This is a test of VB scripting driving Lotus Notes 7 "  
end with
```

Originally I did not want to comment on the quality of the copied code at all. But the discussion with Lankymart made me think, it would be good to comment on it.

```vb
Set oSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
```

This line creates an OLE interface to a running Notes- Client. If client does not run, then it will be started. If you used `Set oSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")` then it would have been a COM- Object you get. Be aware, that Some OLE- Methods do not work in COM and vice versa. e.g. `oCurrentMailDb.OPENMAIL` is OLE, while the same thing in COM would be `oCurrentMailDb.OpenMailDatabase()`

```vb
' eg. CN=Michael V Green/OU=CORPAU/OU=WBCAU/O=WBG 
strUserName = oSession.UserName 

strMailDbName = Left(strUserName, 1) & Right(strUserName, (Len(strUserName) - InStr(1, strUserName, "")))&".nsf"
```

Getting the users' mailfile is completely nonsense, the code will get everything but a correct filename. As the variable is not used at all - can be forgotten

```vb
set oCurrentMailDb = oSession.CurrentDatabase
```

Just gets the database that is currently open in the client. If no database is open, an error will be thrown in the next wscript.echo- line, and we will never get to the next lines where it checks, if a database is open...

The problem with this line: Sending mails is possible from ANY database in Lotus Notes. If the database that is open e.g. is the personal addressbook, then the mail will be saved and sent from there (and you will never find it in the Sent- View of your mailfile.

I would suggest to use OPENMAIL first and only do a fallback to the currently open database if that fails.

The rest of the code seems to be OK.

Comment: `as String`? Not in VBScript everything is `Variant` nothing is strongly typed.

Comment: Ditch the array, and use Split, like in .sendTo= Split("addr1,addr2,addr3", ",")

Comment: @D.Bugger Or `.SendTo = Array("...", "...", "...")`

Comment: Thanks guys it worked fine if I define as per above comment. Thanks guys

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Hi guys If I want to send a mail from other mail box which is opened along with my email, what I need to change?  I tried with few changes but no luck

Comment: you just need to change the line `strMailDbName = ` to point to the path of the other mail database

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of email address strings and set CopyTo to that array:

```
Dim addresses (2)
addresses(0) = "EMAIL" 
addresses(1) = "EMAIL" 
addresses(2) = "EMAIL"

with oMailDoc 
    .SendTo = "migreen@westpac.com.au" 
    .BlindCopyTo = "mgreen@ozemail.com.au"  
    .CopyTo = addresses 
    .Subject = "This is a test of VB scripting driving Lotus Notes 7 "  
end with
```